# Unable to open popup using Ionic + IBM Cloud App ID

Tags: ionic-framework, ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I´m developing an mobile application using Ionic and Angular
Ionic:

```
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.0.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
@angular-devkit/schematics : 8.3.26
@angular/cli : 8.3.26
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 2.2.0
```

```
Cordova:
Cordova CLI : 10.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 7 other plugins)
```

```
Utility:
cordova-res (update available: 0.14.0) : 0.10.0
native-run (update available: 1.0.0) : 0.3.0
```

```
System:
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android\sdk)
NodeJS : v14.2.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
npm : 6.14.4
OS : Windows 10
```

I´m using IBM Cloud App ID single page application authentication and follow these guides:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmcloud-appid-js
- https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/secure-your-single-page-angular-apps-using-app-id

The SPA Authentication opens a popup to allow user to type in the credentials.
Since I´m running the device application( not web ), the pop ups does not get open and I get the error: "Unable to open popup".

Is it possible to have the device open the popup? It works fine when run the application inside a browser  out the device.
The application must run on a device, because it uses the device camera to read QRCode.